# How should I dress for Jury Selection?

Tags: jury

I have been chosen, after filling out a questionnaire, to appear for jury selection.  I have no desire to influence whether or not I am chosen, but at the same time I wish to appear respectable.  What would be considered appropriate attire for Jury Selection?  I haven't had to wear a suit since my father's  funeral, and haven't needed to wear anything more formal than jeans and a tee shirt other than for job interviews in the past decade.

Comment: Where are you located?  Local customs may vary.  In the US, you will usually find that the court's website addresses this question, and the answer is typically "business casual".

Comment: As an example, here is the web page for [St Louis City](https://www.stlouis-mo.gov/services/jury-duty.cfm) where it says that jeans are ok, but shorts, tank tops and t-shirts are not.

Comment: Well, jury selection is kind of like a job interview...

Comment: Here in Canada, our head of state is Queen Elizabeth (of Britain). One person my sister knows has been up for jury duty several times, and always wears a t-shirt with a picture of HRH with a safety pin through her nose. He never gets picked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally the rules on jury service state that there is some local standard, typically business casual, on dress. I don't know of any legal authority that has enforced this attire requirement. So if this local rules requirement can actually be enforced is an open question.